# Access DB from adapter (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I have a list of categories and i want to show the amount of items in each category. Using Room with MVVM architecture basically i want to use simple query in my adapter, to return its value (amount of items)

**DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM items WHERE listId=:listID")
suspend fun countItems(listID: Long):Int
```

**Repo**

```
suspend fun countItems(id: Long): Int{
        return itemsDao.countItems(id)
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class ListsAdapter internal constructor(
    context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListsAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var lists = mutableListOf<ListItem>()

    inner class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val listName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_list_name)
        val listIcon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_list_icon)
        val wAmount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_list_amount)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListsAdapter.ListViewHolder {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list, parent, false)
        return ListViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = lists.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListsAdapter.ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = lists[position]
        holder.listName.text = current.name
     // holder.wAmount.text =

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val bundle = bundleOf("list_id" to current.id,"list_name" to current.name)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listsFragment_to_nav_items_list, bundle)
        }
    }

    internal fun setLists(lists: List<ListItem>) {
        this.lists = lists.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    internal fun listToDelete(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) : ListItem{
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        return lists[position]
    }

    internal fun removeList(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder){
        lists.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }
}
```

Should it be done over ViewModel, but in that case it has to be passed to adapter? Or maybe there is better (cleaner) way to do it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Access db from viewmodel instead of from adapter and pass data to adapter

Comment: Use an `interface` to let the View that is using the adapter 'observe' the change, then let that View call your method from ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Adapters shouldn't be responsible for loading data from storage. The clean way to do it is to access the repo in your `ViewModel`, then pass the data to your `Adapter`. This also gives you the benefit of being able to handle errors in a straightforward way, as it would be easy to update the layout containing `Adapter` easily, unlike the spaghetti you'll need to do this from the adapter, in the addition to being a wrong design of course.

Another step would be to introduce a more layered architecture,like [Uncle Bob's clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)